# How do I make sure RegexSerDe is available to my Hadoop nodes?

Tags: hadoop, hive, classnotfoundexception, elastic-map-reduce

I'm trying to attack the problem of analyzing web logs with Hive, and I've seen plenty of examples out there, but I can't seem to find anyone with this specific issue.

Here's where I'm at: I've set up an AWS ElasticMapReduce cluster, I can log in, and I fire up Hive.  I make sure to `add jar hive-contrib-0.8.1.jar`, and it says it's loaded.  I create a table called `event_log_raw`, with a few string columns and a regex.  `load data inpath '/user/hadoop/tmp overwrite into table event_log_raw`, and I'm off to the races. `select * from event_log_raw` works (I think locally, as I don't get the map % and reduce % outputs), and I get my 10 records from my sample data, parsed correctly, everything's good.  `select count(*) from event_log_raw` works as well, this time with a mapreduce job created.

I want to convert my `request_url` field to a map, so I run:

```
select elr.view_time as event_time, elr.ip as ip, 
str_to_map(split(elr.request_url," ")[1],"&","=") as params 
from event_log_raw elr
```

Mapreduce fires up, waiting, waiting...FAILED.

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
```

I check the syslogs from the task trackers and see, among other things,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
<snip>
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.setChildren(MapOperator.java:406)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:90)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe
```

I've google'd and SO'ed this, but I guess my google-fu is not up to snuff.  Everything I've found points to folks having trouble with this and solving it by running the `add jar` command.  I've tried that, I've tried adding it to my `hive-site.xml`, I've tried having it locally, tried putting the jar in an s3 bucket.  Tried adding a bootstrap step to add it during the bootstrap phase (disaster).

Can anyone help me figure out a.) why my task nodes can't find RegexSerDe, and b.) how to make this work?  Links are welcome as well, if they might reveal something more than just running `add jar`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is to add all these jars to hadoop's lib directory on all the task-trackers, we do this with a bunch of stuff:

```
scp library.jar task-tracker-1:~/<HADOOP_HOME>/lib/
```

or with EMR in the bootstrap script:

```
s3cmd get s3://path/to/lib.jar /home/hadoop/lib/
```

When we used EMR, we just had a s3 directory full of jars that we would sync to the hadoop lib directory:

```
s3cmd sync s3://static/jars/ /home/hadoop/jars
cp jars/*.jar lib/
```

If you use oozie, you could also put the jars in the oozie.share.lib directory.

Comment: I added a .sh script to s3 with the `s3cmd get ...` in it, and tried to create a new cluster, but that bailed out with a non-zero return code.  Turns out s3cmd needs a .s3cfg file.  Is it possible to scp the files out of s3 instead of using s3cmd?

In the meantime, I manually scp'ed the jars over to my hadoop nodes, and it seems to be working (as in, I'm getting a new, unrelated error).  This has been a great help, though I'm still curious why `add jar ...` didn't work as (seemingly) advertised.  Isn't that command supposed to handle getting jars around to your other nodes?

Comment: Do you run ADD JAR for every hive terminal session? ADD JAR is temporary, so if you start a new hive session you have to do it again.

Comment: Yea, I do. At least, I'm pretty sure I do.  Maybe I had restarted hive and forgotten to ADD JAR again when I got this error.  I'll be starting a new EMR jobflow today, so I'll double-check this all again.  Thanks again.

Comment: As an aside, how did you get s3cmd configured in your EMR bootstrap script?  Do you have something that outputs or downloads your .s3cfg file?

Comment: no, there are AWS credentials on the box when it starts up, so you can just copy those. can't remember where they live at the moment. It's easier to just use the hadoop fs client honestly, it can read/write to s3 fine.

Comment: alright, thanks for all the info!  I'm not 100% of the way there, but this has allowed me to make some progress.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I copied the serde jar file to the

```
hadoop/lib
```

directory and also did a restart of the hadoop (or even the server) to really work.

Answer (score -1):

I guess all you need is to add this jar file into `HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH` variable 
for e.g.

If your `hive-contrib-0.8.1.jar` is at `/usr/hive/lib`
then run

`export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=/usr/hive/lib/hive-contrib-0.8.1.jar:$HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH`

or if `HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH` does not exist , just run

`export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=/usr/hive/lib/hive-contrib-0.8.1.jar`.

After that start the hive session and you will see that everything just works fine.

In case you need this variable permanently put this into `.profile` file or `.bash_profile` based on your operating system